# mysql - optimizing a where clause with many < tests

Tags: mysql, optimization

I get an innoDB table of ~400K records. Rarely (if not never) updated.

Most frequent requests are select count(*) with a where clause composed of several conditions in logical AND as follows :

A = value (int, indexed, values ranging from 4 to 14)
B = value (varchar(1), indexed, 26 different possible values)

Then come a variable number of Cx < value conditions (from 0 to 26 conditions)
Each Cx matching a column of int type, values ranging from 0 to 7.

Cx columns are initially not indexed. I tried indexing them with no noticeable performance impact.

Any idea of optimization of that query is welcome.

Apart from trying to optimize that query per se, I am also in a second level of optimization in a situation where I get about 25 consécutive requests to be made, each having an identical set of Cx conditions but different values for A and B.

Do you think that building a temporary table from the set of Cx conditions alone, then selecting from that temp table with conditions on A et B would be profictable ?

**------------------**

**UPDATE 1**
Thinking about reforging the query and adding extra fields to the table... I had forgotten some basis, thanks to Bernd, Bob and Rick for having brought me down to basis.

A/ Being said that this table is rarely if never updated, I changed the engine for MyISAM.
Apart from squeezing its size down to 2/3rd of it's original innoDBsize, this increased the performance of the queries by 25%.

B/ I then considered the poor cardinality of the A and B indexes. Added to the fact that explains the considerable difference between my configuration and Bob's one. :
The distribution of values in A and B columns are far from random. They are near to perfect gaussians with, for instance mean-A = 10 and stdev-A = 1, this telling that the vast majority of the population get A = {9,10,11} which renders the associated index definitively not selective.
Observation is similar for B.

Being said that B is not in fact a single column but can be columns B1,B2,B3,B4, I defined 4 composite indexes (A,Bi) which resulted in performances multiplied by 4.

So all in all performances multiplied by 5.

I am close to happy!
Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: create a useful (composite) index and optimize the query, but i cat see them

Comment: Do you mean for example adding 26 composite indexes (A,B,c1),(A,B,c2)... ? or one composite index (c1,c2,...,C26) ?

Comment: Only One Composite Index . And the Order of the Field are impotent. The Field that reduce the result Most Must be the First And so on

Comment: Well, being said that a composite index is limited to 16 cols, I will need at least two. I am going to try that taking some stats into account in order to determine the ordrer. Thanks a lot for the tip.

Comment: By the way I am puzzled by your "the field that reduce the result most" precision. Being that I can get a variable number of Ci statements, would'nt it be more efficient to set first the most frequently used Ci irrespective of the fact that it will be the one which reduces the less. v.g. to order according to the frequence of use rather than to their "reducing" factor ?

Comment: Anyway, let's forget composite indexes, I read elsewhere on stackoverflow that comparisons other than = do not benefit from composite indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you do not need any additional optimization of query. If it works slow, you need to check the database settings. Or, it may be some hardware problems.
I had some tests on small virtual server (1 CPU, 512M RAM) :

```
   mysql> create table t (a int(1), b varchar(1), c1 int(1), c2 int(1), c3 int(1), c4 int(1));
   mysql> create index ia on t(a) ;
   mysql> create index ib on t(b) ;
```

Then, i'd load 400 000 sets of a random data

```
insert into t values
(6, 'T', 4, 6, 3, 4),
(12, 'z', 3, 5, 6, 1),
...

mysql> select count(*) from t where a=5 and b='x' and c1 > 5;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      340 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Looks good without any extra tuning

Comment: Thanks for testing Bob. The first thing is that in the reality I can get up to 26 (c1 > 5)-like statements (c1 < 5) AND (c2 < 7) AND (c3 < 1)... which makes the timings increasing significantly. The second thing is that am not owner on the mysql-server which makes so I just cannot change database settings.

Comment: Anyway, it must not to be a problem for 400K-size database. Possible, you have corrupt table or indexes?
try create another table with the same schema and copy your data to the new one 
insert into t1 select a, b, c1, c2, c3, c4, ... from t ;
It takes several seconds

Comment: Had already done that and am rather confident that neither table nor indexes are corrupted. I however acknowledge something wrong somewhere since the figures I get are about 10 times higher that yours.

Comment: Can you paste here output 
`show create table`
and exactly query from general.log ?

Comment: @aCOSwt - How big is the table?  How much RAM?  What values for: key_buffer_size, innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Answer (score -1):

```
INDEX(a,b,c1)
```

`a` and `b` need to be first since they are tested with `=`.  Then pick one of the c's.  All queries will benefit from `a` and `b`; one will benefit further.

(It does not matter which comes first, `a` or `b`; the performance will be the same.)

Yes, you could have 26 of them.  Maybe that is better.

To make the table smaller (hence possibly faster), change the 4-byte `INTs` to 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (assuming the values are between 0 and 255).

Comment: Thanks Rick. INTs are already unsigned tinyints. And the problem is that B is not a single column. It can be B1, B2, B3 and B4. So making (A,Bi,Cj) composite indexes would lead to 4x26 indexes.

Comment: Then go with only 4:  (A, Bi).  Not perfect, but hopefully better than what you have now.  If you could explain what the columns mean, maybe we could come up with a workaround that somehow takes advantage of that meaning.